# How to get Class Object of an ArrayList type?

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to access a method through reflection, and the `getMethod()` function requires a class for the parameter type. The parameter is a Class object, and I'm not sure how to get this from an `ArrayList<String>` type. Here is my current code, where I would want to change `String.class`:

```
Method m = o.getClass().getMethod(method, String.class);
```

Comment: can you give us the code of the method you want to call ? and definition of `method`

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear (at least for me). If "The parameter is a Class object" then pass `Class.class` as type representing required parameter. "*I'm not sure how to get this from an ArrayList<String> type*" what does it have to do with ArrayList<String>?

Comment: `method` is simply a String containing the method name. The method's prototype, as an example, looks like: `public static void Method(ArrayList<String> options);`. This works if I _do_ use a String type as a parameter, but I would much rather prefer to use an ArrayList in this case.

Comment: To call a method through reflection, it requires a parameter type for the method you are calling. See my other comment.

Comment: @Sergix You'll just have to pass `ArrayList.class`. Types are erased so there's no `ArrayList<String>.class`.

Answer (score 1):

For your method signature

```
public static void method(ArrayList<String> options);
```

you can simply get the `Method` using

```
Method m = o.getClass().getMethod(method, ArrayList.class);
```

Comment: Thanks!! That worked.